# need to close Modal Dialog Box on Windows 10 IoT Embedded system

Tags: modal-dialog, windows-10, embedded, registry, windows-embedded

On an embedded system, some software that we want to run will have a '*modal Dialog box*' pop up informing of an error, and the software waits for the user to press `[OK]` (it was originally designed to not be used on an embedded system).

We want a windows setting that will automatically address the windows of this type. 
To do that on a previous iteration, we would change the register `EnableDefaultReply` on *Windows 7*

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Error Message Instrument:
REG_DWORD EnableDefaultReply
```

However, that doesn't seem available on *Windows 10 IoT Embedded*.

We can potentially just automate a click when that window pops up, but we'd prefer to do the Windows 10 equivalent if there exists one.

Thank you.